# Why google-chrome-stable requires libX11.so.6()(64bit) but this requirement cannot be provided?

Tags: x11, chrome, sles

I'm used to google chrome, so I downloaded it onto my sles 11 sp3. when I want to install it, I get the following issue.

```
Problem: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.x86_64 requires libX11.so.6()(64bit), but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: xorg-x11-libX11-7.4-5.9.1.x86_64[SLES11-SP3-Pool]
 Solution 1: do not install google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

The problem is:

I can see package: xorg-x11-libX11 is installed in yast2, version is 7.4-5.11.11.1.

And I can see libX11.so.6 is sitting in `/usr/lib64/`,

```
libX11.so
libX11.so.6
libX11.so.6.2.0
```

Why is chrome still telling me libX11.so.6()(64bit) can't be provided?

And what does `uninstallable providers: xorg-x11-libX11-7.4-5.9.1.x86_64[SLES11-SP3-Pool]` mean? From what I see that the version installed: `7.4-5.11.11.1` is already higher than the version it requires.

Comment: Can you tell us the URL you downloaded the google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.125-1.x86_64 package from?

Comment: http://www.google.com/chrome/, I selected `64 bit .rpm (For Fedora/openSUSE)` version

Answer (score 0):

This [troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.microfocus.com/index.php/SUSE_Manager/SolverTestcase) suggests it's either metadata cache corruption or genuinely broken package (missing 'provides: libX11.so.6()(64bit)').